# Parse a file to a variable from request body golang

Tags: api, go, types, minio

I'm creating an API for uploading images to MinIO server and I need to send files in the request body. Then I need to get the file and pass io.Reader type variable into a function that will add it to the bucket. I don't know what data type I have to put in the body struct for this field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question to include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I actually figured it out:

```
type Body struct {
    recipe_id string                `form:"recipe_id"`
    image     *multipart.FileHeader `form:"file"`
}

file_header, err := c.FormFile("file")
file, err := file_header.Open()
```